# Font-Awesome in Rails 5 not getting precompiled

Tags: font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-5

we recently updated from Rails 4.2.7 to Rails 5 and now we are having an issue with Font-Awesome when we precompile the assets.

We include the [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem (v4.7.0.0) and everything works fine in development.
But if we run `rails assets:precompile` (it doesn't matter if in dev or production env) the fonts are not appearing in `public/assets`.

Our `manifest.js` looks like this:

```
# app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link emails/base.css
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../fonts
```

Our `assets.rb` is the default one, as you config it now in the manifest.js

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '2.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

We are using sass in our Application with the `sass-rails` gem from `master`

Does anyone have an idea what is the problem here?

Regards,
spa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.
If I add

```
%w(eot svg ttf woff woff2).each do |ext|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << "fontawesome-webfont.#{ext}"
end
```

to the `assets.rb` initializer, everything works fine.
I thought you skip that part, as you should just use the new `manifest.js` now.

Again what learned.

Answer (score 0):

Just put fonts under `app/assets/fonts` , and modify url('Your Font Path') to font-url('Your Font Path') in your scss. Asset Pipeline will auto precompile fonts into `public/assests` folder.